# Flutter GETX: How to update Get.defaultDialog(...) data from the controller

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-getx

A button opens alert dialog with GETX (Get.defaultDialog) and I have an image picker button with Image.File(...) in the dialog and when I pick the image from the gallery the image doesnt get updated only if I leave the dialog and open another one
I want to update the Image.File after selecting the image with GETX

I tried update(); in the controller function didnt update and I tired the GetxBuilder in the dialog but I get an error

first file

```
imageController controller = Get.put(imageController());
alertAddProduct() {
  Get.defaultDialog(
      title: "Add product",
      middleText: "Add product",
      //radius: 20,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      content: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: controller.imagePath != null ? Image.file(controller.imagePath,errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
            return const Text("Bruh");
          },): const Text("Pick image")
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              controller.getImage();
            },
            child: const Text("Select image"),
          )
        ]
      ),
      actions: [
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // working on it
            },
            child: const Text("Yes")),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Get.back();
          },
          child: const Text("No"),
        ),
      ],);
}
```

and the controller file

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class imageController extends GetxController {
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  var imagePath;
  void getImage() async {
  final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
  final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,    
    );
  if (image != null) {
    print("----------------------------" + image.path);
    imagePath = File(image.path);
    update();
  } else {
    print("---------------------------- Please select image");
  }
}


}
```

and the main file

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        elevation: 5,
        onPressed: (() {
          alertAddProduct();
        }),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
```

Comment: can u share the code here

Comment: @MidlajNazar I updated the question with the codes please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case You are trying to make any updates in dialog **update();** method will not work because till I know this method can update the context only not any kind of overlay,
so if you want to update the image after selecting Show in the dialog you have to rebuild it so it can reflect your image.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Title of Dialog"),
          content: Text(contentText),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text("Cancel"),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  contentText = "Changed Content of Dialog";
                });
              },
              child: Text("Change"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: I want to update it with getx but I will try this

Comment: you can use as same just start with StatefulBuilder instead of starting from column[]

Answer (score 0):

change you imagePath variable to obs  and wrap the UI with OBX

eg:
In the Controller

```
var imagePath = ''.obs ;
....
imagePath.value = File(image.path);
// update ---> remove update line
```

In the UI wrap with Obx eg:

```
....
Obx(()=>Container(
child: 
//Add string instead of null on comparing 
controller.imagePath.value != '' ? 
Image.file(controller.imagePath.value,errorBuilder: 
(context, error, stackTrace) {
return const Text("Bruh");},) : const Text("Pick 
image")
)),
....
```